# How imresize works when downsampling an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I don't clearly understand how imresize works, especially when we are downscaling an image (say from 4x4 to 2x2). When we're upscaling it's easier to understand. I mean we've to just find intermediate points by either seeing which known point is closer (method = 'nearest') or use linear averaging of 4 closest known points (method = 'bilinear') and so on. We do not need any filter for this right?

And my main doubt is when we downscale. I understand from signal processing classes that to avoid aliasing a smoothening low pass filter must be applied before we decimate intermediate values. But which filter is MATLAB using? They just say methods and I don't understand how we can use 'bilinear' or 'bicubic' as a kernel.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: One more question. what if I want to use a gaussian kernel for downscaling? How do I achieve that?

Comment: Or can anyone simply tell me which kernel do they use if we simply type 

     imresize(I,0.5); 

without any method or kernel specification. I would like to know the  blurring kernel which does the LP filtering. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for the function seems to be incomplete. Open the imresize.m (`edit imresize`) and take a look at the `contributions`-function.

There you can see, that matlab is not using a 2x2 neibourhood when using the `bilinear` or `bicubic`-method and downscaling. The kernel size is increased to avoid aliasing.

---

Some explanations about the Math behind imresize. To simplify, I will explain the 1D case only. When a scale <1 is used, the window size is increased. This means, the resulting value is no longer the weighted average of the 2 (2x2 for images) Neighbours.  Instead a larger window size of w (wxw) is used.

Start with the standard method:

[image: Std]

The Image shows the common case, two known grid values averaged to a new one with the weights 1/5 and 4/5. Instead of the well known definition, the weights could also be defined drawing a triangle with the base w=2:

[image: With triangle w=1]

Now increasing the base of the triangle, we get the weights for a larger window size. A base of w=6 is drawn:

[image: w=3]

The new triangle defines the weight over 6 points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my doubt is how can we use 'bilinear' or 'bicubic' as kernel when downscaling? Aren't they only interpolation methods? Only 'box' or such kernels should be applicable for downscaling right?

Comment: @akhilc: I added some explanations about the math behind the linear method.